# Unable to access AppSettings from App.Config in a Class Library Project

Tags: vb.net, app-config

I am trying to access appSettings using the following syntax and I have used it before in my many website projects but not in a class library project. In this class library project I cannot even access the AppSettings Keys.  Is there any way I could access the AppSettings Key from my class?  Is the class library project's app.config or project structure behave in a different way?

```
 Dim SharedDrive As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("scriptsfolder")

<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="scriptsfolder" value="C:\BadTempScripts"/>
  </appSettings>
```

I have already added Project Reference to System.Configuration and imported in my class.  When I run my code it says, "Object not set to an instance of any object".

Comment: You are using two different key names - "Scripts" and "scriptsFolder"

Comment: I noticed that changed that but the error remains the same. I trying different options and will update soon. thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A library runs in the context of an application, not by itself.

You need to put the configuration in the `.config` file of the application that will use the library.

So, if your library is `lib.dll` and the application is `myApp.exe`, you should use a `.config` file `myApp.exe.config`.

As an alternative for using a `.config` file, consider passing in the configuration as a dependency to your library types.

---

You have a specific bug in your code, in that you are trying to call a key `Scripts` where your configuration has a key `scriptsfolder`.

Comment: @Mitul - And the .config file name?

Comment: The confusion is this. In one of my class library project it works perfect. Same lines of code works fine but in this project it doesn't.  I don't know why and both are class library projects.  I have both projects side by side right now.

Comment: Are both libraries used in the same application?

Comment: THe one in which it is working is a standalone classlibrary project.  the onein which it is not working is a class library project and startup project is a console application with no app.config file.  And I am trying to get keys inside my class lib project class.

Comment: @Mitul - "THe one in which it is working is a standalone classlibrary project" - that's not possible. A class library cannot run by itself. You have a _console application_ which uses it. The config file being used is the one that belongs to the console application.

Comment: I think I know why it is working because earlier it was a webservice project and I explicitly changed the project type from project properties to class library proj. I didn't meant to start that way though.  I agree it shouldn't work.

Comment: @Mitul - That has nothing to do with it. The console application has the correct config settings, that's why it works.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and, as Oded tell us, a library run in the context of an application, however I was unable to solve the problem. In the end I used this code:

```
Dim config As Configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Application.ExecutablePath);
Dim k as KeyValueConfigurationElement = config.AppSettings.Settings
("SVCInstalled")
 If k <> Nothing Then
 If k.Value <> Nothing Then
 ' Process your data next
```

Note, I'm translating from C# on-the-fly, so excuse me if something is wrong